# How would I curry the String.format function to use it with map over an array?

Tags: scala

I have an array of strings and I need to turn them into quoted strings. Obviously I could just iterate over the array and use something like `"\"%s\"".format(elem)` to replace each element, but this seems grungy considering that my next step would be `arr.mkString("(", "OR", ")")`

I tried to curry String.format as follows:

```
val curried = "\"%s\"".format(_)
arr.map(curried)
```

But that does not work and complains:

```
 found   : (Any*) => String
 required: (java.lang.String) => ?
```

How do I map a function like String.format over an array of strings? Is there another way to curry it or should I perhaps be specifying types?

Comment: `format` receives a vararg, so you can't really curry it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to help compiler a little bit, and specify the desired type (at least it's one of the possible solutions to your problem):

```
val curried = "\"%s\"".format(_: String)
```

Otherwise compiler will produce `Seq[Any] => String` function, because `format` method has varargs.

Comment: Excellent. That works perfectly and I now understand what that _ is really doing there.

Answer (score 1):

By writing a generic `unvararg` perhaps. (A function that converts `(A*) => B` to `Seq[A] => B`.)

```
scala> def unvararg[A, B](f: (A*) => B): Seq[A] => B = x => f(x: _*)
unvararg: [A, B](f: A* => B)Seq[A] => B

scala> def seqSingleton[A](x: A): Seq[A] = Seq(x)
seqSingleton: [A](x: A)Seq[A]

scala> val ss = Array("hello", "world")
ss: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(hello, world) 

scala> ss.map((seqSingleton[String] _) andThen unvararg("\"%s\"".format))
res8: Array[String] = Array("hello", "world")
```

Comment: Seems that Scala 2.10.0-M1 makes `unvararg` unnecessary. For the following example: `scala> val curried = "\"%s\"".format(_)` REPL returns `curried: Seq[Any] => String = <function1>`, but Scala 2.9.1 will print `curried: Any* => String = <function1>`.